# Customise UserStore<T> class - EF core implementation of IUserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

Iam trying to override one of the inherited method of UserStore class.

```
public class MyUserStore: UserStore<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

But i get an error saying "no suitable method found to override".But there is a method with that signature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserstore-1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IUserStore_1_FindByIdAsync_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Comment: but signature isn't the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method that you are trying to override includes a CancellationToken parameter:

`FindByIdAsync(String, CancellationToken)`

Your method should be:

```
public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `CancellationToken` parameter:

```
Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Note: after typing "override", Intellisense presents you a list of overridable members. Select one and type <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete. You will **automatically** get the right signature.